# Power BI Slicer with two different tables don´t work

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem with my Power BI charts. I have two tables which are structured like this:

Table 1: Articles, sold, total,...
Table 2: Date, Item 1, Item 2, ...

I made two tables out of it. A column chart from the first table and a line chart from the second table.

Now I want to create a slicer chart. There I added the Articles from the Table 1. Logically, this currently only filters the column chart.

My question is: Is it possible to connect it somehow in such a way that both tables are filtered? If so, how can I implement that?

I have already tried to transpose table 2. But then I have a problem with the dates in the line chart.

I hope someone can help me. THANKS!

Comment: I have to unpivot my table 2 to solve this problem.